# Change column position using JSON sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

Is it possible to change the positions of the columns in a JSON template? I have ordered them within the JSON file, but once the template runs the default sharepoint columns still show in the original position.

Example

I would like Version column to appear first, Name column to appear second, and Program column to appear third.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your field order by view settings.

[image]

Or If you use view formatting, you could hide the header

```
"schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting#build-custom-row-layouts

Comment: I understood the view settings portion but I need this to happen on a template. Each time the template is ran I need the all documents view to display a certain way. So I do not have to manually do it each time a site is created. 

maybe i am not understanding the hiding a header portion, wouldn't that just get rid of a column?